# Create three lines following element using pseudo class/elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a heading element on my page to look like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ggZvb3s.png?1]

I saw the steps shown at [CSS: :before and :after pseudo elements in practice](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice) (see heading 'Styling titles') which displays a single line before and after the heading element. I liked that idea and wanted to expand it out to display three lines as per the sample image. Unlike image I was hoping for the lines to be thinner and not take up the full height space available but that's all I could mock up with limited tools/skills.

My issue is not getting three lines, but rather aligning each of those lines to their intended place. Currently they mess up and stack in an unexpected way (at least unexpected from my understanding).

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur69nd6a/) showing my progress so far. I've created the `h1` for text and two `span`s either side of the text but within the `h1`. My reasoning for this was to remove the single line from the `h1` and apply the three lines via each `span` utilising pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before` for two of them.

Not sure where I have gone wrong or if it is even possible. I have complete access to HTML and CSS so the structure and styles are not locked down.

Let me know if I haven't been clear.

Comment: Are you only looking to tweak the code inline with your explanation in question (or) are you ok with alternate approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using two `span`s.

[image]

```css
.long {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.long:after, .long:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: -34px;
}
.long:before {
  left: calc(100% + 4px);
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.title:after, .title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  top: calc(100% - 31.2%*2);
  right: -24px;
}
.title:before {
  right: calc(100% + 4px)
}
```

```html
<span class="title"><span class="long">text</span></span>
```

Also, possible with `svg` if you want round corners.

[image]

```html
<svg width="170" height="50" viewBox="-10 0 170 50">
  <defs>
    <line id="small" x1="3" y1="3" x2="20" y2="3" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <line id="large" x1="3" y1="3" x2="30" y2="3" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" />
  </defs>
  <text x="75" y="35" text-anchor="middle" font-size="50">text</text>
  <use transform="translate(5,10)" xlink:href="#small" />
  <use transform="translate(-5,17)" xlink:href="#large" />
  <use transform="translate(5,24)" xlink:href="#small" />
  <use transform="translate(125,10)" xlink:href="#small" />
  <use transform="translate(125,17)" xlink:href="#large" />
  <use transform="translate(125,24)" xlink:href="#small" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! I've never seen the calc() CSS function before so here is a reference for others https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc. I've had no exposure to the <svg> element but it looks like a great alternative and probably a better solution looking forward.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a left and right image and display it with the `:before` and `:after` like you are but instead of setting `content:` add `background: url('img_left.png');`?

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur69nd6a/2/)** to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS background image, or gradient to achieve the same effect.

The CSS background will be something along the lines of:

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #fff 40%, #fff 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #fff 80%, #fff 100%);
```